# API Instagram - After Login - Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, request, instagram

I'm new on programming language (JavaScript) but I interested to learning more about this. For that, I use the Instagram API to do request and read responses from urls.

My objective is do a simple "Instagram", with simple UI.

My question is: I need to authenticate on instagram to receive a AccessToken, and apply on future requests.

Anybody help me?

Thanks a lot

Documentation:
https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

This is way to broad of a question. What have you tried? What have been your outcomes? Where is your code?
My suggestion is to learn JavaScript in other ways than making an API call, as doing this can be complicated especially if your new to JS.